# Returning a copy of an object stack in java

Tags: java, list, linked-list, stack, reverse

I have a stack method that's **supposed** to return a **reversed** **copy** of the **`this`** object. 
I need **`this`** object to link to **`that`** object. Thanks.

**Update**

To clarify,
the **that** stack object that's created pushes items that are popped from the **this object.**
I want the **this object** to reference the **that object** after the **this object** gets empty. What I really want is to return a reversed copy of the **this object**. Clear?

```
public LinkedStack<E> reversed()
{
    LinkedStack<E> that= new LinkedStack<E>();
    if(this.isEmpty()){
        return this;
    }
    else{
        while(top!=null)
            {
                that.push(pop());
            }
        }
    return this;
    }
```

Full class

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
//import java.util.Stack;
public class LinkedStack<E>{
    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    public class Node<E>{
        private E info;
        private Node<E> link;
        public Node(E info,Node<E>link){
            this.info=info;
            this.link=link;
        }//Node constructor
    public void Setinfo(E info){this.info =info;}

    public E getinfo(){return info;}

    public void setLink(Node<E> newLink){this.link=newLink;}

    public Node<E> getLink(){return this.link;}
}//end of node

protected Node<E> upnode;
public LinkedStack(){
    upnode=null;
}

//isEmpty method
public boolean isEmpty(){
    if(upnode==null){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
//item push
public void push(E item)
{
    Node<E> sth=new Node<E>(item,upnode);
    sth.setLink(upnode);
    upnode=sth;
}
//LinkedStack push
public void push(LinkedStack<E> s)
{
    if(s.isEmpty()==true)
    {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    else{
        while(!(s.isEmpty()))
        {
            this.push(s.pop());
        }

    }
}
//peek method
public E peek()
    {
    if(upnode==null){
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    else
        return upnode.getinfo();
    }
//pop method
public E pop()
{
    if(upnode==null){
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    else{
        E item=peek();
        upnode=upnode.link;
        return item;
    }
}

public int size(){
int ct=0;
if(this.isEmpty()==true){
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
else{
    while(this.isEmpty()==false){
        ct++;
        upnode=upnode.getLink();
        }
    }
return ct;
}

//Reverse method
public LinkedStack<E> reversed()
{
    LinkedStack<E> that = new LinkedStack<E>();
    if(this.isEmpty()){
        return this;
    }
    else{
        while(!this.isEmpty())
            {
                that.push(pop());
            }
        }
    return this;
    }
//Returns a string representation of this stack
public String toString()
{
    String result="";
    Node<E> current=upnode;//set the current node to upnode
    while(current !=null)
    {//while link isn't null
        result=result+(current.getinfo()).toString()+"\n";//get info and call toString
        current=current.getLink();//Get the link of the current node
    }
    return result;//return result
    }
}//end of LinkedStack
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: *"I need this to link to that, the reversed copy of the this stack."* - This sentence makes no sense to me.

Comment: The phrasing of this question reminds me of the lyrics to Nuthin' but a 'G' Thang (classic American rap song). Anyway, is the goal to create a custom Stack capable of returning a reversed version of itself?

Comment: I want to make a copy of the object that's created using the class. I want the object created by the class to reference the that object.

Comment: @Vidya. I'm not that into rap, but yes, the goal is to "create a custom Stack capable of returning a reversed version of itself."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `while(top!=null)` to `while(!this.isEmpty())`

Comment: Did that. Ran some tests and object.reversed() returned nothing

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make much sense.  (And neither does your comment below)

But your current approach is definitely wrong because the `this.pop()` operation is going to *change* the state of `this`.

The correct solution will depend on the internal details of the `LinkedStack` class ... which you haven't shown us.

Comment: I want to make a copy of the object that's created using the class. I want the object created by the class to reference the that object after all items from this have been popped of it.

Comment: @pyler - I still don't understand.  (You really need to learn how to write clear and precise English.  It is a *prerequiste* for being a successful programmer!)

Comment: @pyler i really don't get what you want, what i understand is that you want to modify your instance.

Answer (score 0):

As you are modifying your instance, you don't need to create an auxiliar `LinkedStack`

Example:

```
public LinkedStack<E> reversed(){
     int size = size();
     while(size-- > 0){ // to prevent infinite loop
        push(pop());
     }

     return this; // this is not necesary you can make the method void.
}
```

Comment: I want it to return a stack

Comment: As i understood your problem , you want to modify your instance, if you want to return it, return it, but is not necessary.